# MongoS Call Distributions Analysis

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to see how well my shard key is and I thinking to monitor how many calls goes to each shard by the MongoS for each 100 parallel BatchInsert that I do. I probablly can do this at application layer, but is there a way to record this at monogS level?

I am using monogoStat but I  wan the details of monogS. Also, the mongoS log does not say much from what I gather

Answer (score 0):

Do you have trending graphs or some other form of monitoring software? 10gen actually provides a free one called [MMS](http://mms.10gen.com/).

If you are monitoring the activity on your shards, that should correlate to the calls being made from `mongos`. The only caveat here is that activity is not broken out by collection or by database. So if you're sharding multiple DBs on the same instances this may not work.

Otherwise, just look at the activity on the shards and that should clearly tell you what's happening.

Comment: I am really not a big fan of the MMS. I prefer locally monitoring tool like monogostat. remote monitoring like MMS may work for production system but certainly not an option for a developer, at least not for me! by monitoring calls on my shard, how do I know it is not the balancer calls? how do you monitor it? what do you mean by mongostat? that's too manual as 1 million batch inserts does not have in one shot and I have to be gathering data manually for every portional insert?.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mongostat --discover` you can see the traffic per shard as well as the total traffic going through the mongos that mongostat is using. This should give you full insight unto your load distribution in real time.

Note that your shard key always "works" because MongoDB splits on your shard key median rather than simply split the data in two so provided your shard key has high enough cardinality your data will always be perfectly balanced (provided the balancer had time to balance the chunks appropriately)

Comment: The monogoStat that I mentioned is that actually doing so but I need to know out of the 1 million inserts for my tests, which one went where and why some of them are taking much longers than the others by looking at the shard key of the time consuming ones and see what happen to those which are finishing longer?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MMS and mongostat, you can also see the overall status and health of your sharding cluster via the `printShardingStatus()` function, as [outlined here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2676-how-to-work-with-mongodbs-shell-interface/)

Comment: That doe not tell me much about my call distributions. That's just the sharding chunk count on each shard.